# do successive parallel computations require distribute definitions at each intermediate step?

Tags: parallelization

Suppose I am doing a parallel computation, say, using parallel table. I distribute necessary definitions to all kernels. After computation is done, I would like to use the first result in another parallel computation. Do I need to distribute the result of first computation to the kernels? Or since the first computation was parallel, do kernels already know the first result?